# How do you progress through the Droid Explorer unpack option?

Tags: droid-explorer

I'm using a Windows 7 PC and am trying to unpack an *.ab backup file created using Helium. If I right-click on the file in Windows Explorer and select the Unpack option that now appears after installing Droid Explorer 0.9.0.4, I'm first asked for a password. I provided none when creating the backup, so I simply leave the password field blank and press OK to continue.

Then, something weird pops up, and I'm not sure how to continue. I see this window, asking me what I want to open java.exe with:

[image]

Is that supposed to pop up at this point? Am I missing something that should be installed that would avoid this? I have Java 8 Update 31 currently installed on this machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not interfacing with Android. It's about a program  on PC which has some issue with a file (happens to be an Android backup).

Comment: @Firelord - completely understood.  The developer of this program asks for people to pose questions about it here, though.

Comment: I see. [Ryan Conrad](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/1951/ryan-conrad) is the lead developer and usually follows the tag in question. May be he can clear what kind of questions does he expect to be posted here.

Comment: So this question, sort of looks like it could be answered here. I don't think it is a bug with droid explorer, because in the 2 environments I tested this in, I do not have this dialog. It looks like it could be an issue with your install of java. maybe your java path is not added to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Weird, that was (sort of) it!  Java was in fact in my PATH environment variable, but it was using the directory C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\ which contains only 3 symlinks to my actual Java bin folder.  Double clicking on any of the symlink shortcuts results in the window I noted above.  I temporarily changed my PATH variable to point to the real Java folder, and then your Unpack feature worked fine.  (I then put my PATH variable back, since I don't know what potential security issues I'd open myself up to by leaving it altered.)

Comment: @RyanConrad - feel free to throw that recommendation into a quick answer, and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like (as stated in my comment above) that it has to do with the Path of Java not existing in the windows PATH environment variable.

I am adding your comment as well as part of this answer:

> Weird, that was (sort of) it! Java was in fact in my PATH environment variable, but it was using the directory C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\ which contains only 3 symlinks to my actual Java bin folder. Double clicking on any of the symlink shortcuts results in the window I noted above. I temporarily changed my PATH variable to point to the real Java folder, and then your Unpack feature worked fine. (I then put my PATH variable back, since I don't know what potential security issues I'd open myself up to by leaving it altered.)